# Symfony - Login on testing

Tags: php, symfony, testing, authentication

I have issues trying to login on testing.
Following the documentation, I did it this way :

```html
private function logIn()
    {
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        // if you don't define multiple connected firewalls, the context defaults to the firewall name
        // See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        // you may need to use a different token class depending on your application.
        // for example, when using Guard authentication you must instantiate PostAuthenticationGuardToken
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('login', 'password&', $firewallName, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
```

Then in my testing function, I call the login function, request a private page of the website, but it does not work. When I print the crawler, I can see there is something wrong.

```html
$this->logIn($encoder);
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/projects');
var_dump($crawler); 
die();
```

Here is a sample of what I get in the cmd tool :

```html
                                PDOException:
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied

  at vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:46
  at PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=;', 'root', null, array())
     (vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:46)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=;', 'root', null, array())
     (vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver.php:46)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_pgsql', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'url' => '', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => null, 'user' => 'root', 'password' => null, 'driverOptions' => array(), 'serverVersion' => '10.2', 'defaultTableOptions' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'), 'dbname' => ''), 'root', null, array())
     (vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:389)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
     (vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:921)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.looking_date AS looking_date_3, t0.output AS output_4, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_5, t0.created_at AS created_at_6, t0.owner_id AS owner_id_7 FROM project t0', array(), array())
     (vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php:904)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->loadAll(array(), null, null, null)
     (vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php:181)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findBy(array())
     (vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php:164)
  at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findAll()
     (src\Controller\ProjectController.php:49)
  at App\Controller\ProjectController->projectList('projectList')
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:188)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Client.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Client.php:131)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\browser-kit\Client.php:351)
  at Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/projects')
     (tests\Controller\BackendControllerTest.php:51)
  at App\Tests\Util\BackendControllerTest->testHomepage()
  at ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(object(BackendControllerTest), array())
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestCase.php:1071)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest()
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestCase.php:939)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare()
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestResult.php:698)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(object(BackendControllerTest))
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestCase.php:894)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run(object(TestResult))
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:755)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(object(TestResult))
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:755)
  at PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(object(TestResult))
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:545)
  at PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun(object(TestSuite), array('listGroups' => false, 'listSuites' => false, 'listTests' => false, 'listTestsXml' => false, 'loader' => null, 'useDefaultConfiguration' => true, 'loadedExtensions' => array(), 'notLoadedExtensions' => array(), 'colors' => 'always', 'testSuffixes' => array('Test.php', '.phpt'), 'configuration' => object(Configuration), 'debug' => false, 'filter' => false, 'listeners' => array(object(SymfonyTestsListenerForV6)), 'backupGlobals' => false, 'bootstrap' => 'C:\\cygwin64\\home\\www\\navitia-tools\\vendor/autoload.php', 'testdoxGroups' => array(), 'testdoxExcludeGroups' => array(), 'addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist' => true, 'backupStaticAttributes' => null, 'beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState' => null, 'beStrictAboutResourceUsageDuringSmallTests' => false, 'cacheTokens' => false, 'columns' => 80, 'convertDeprecationsToExceptions' => true, 'convertErrorsToExceptions' => true, 'convertNoticesToExceptions' => true, 'convertWarningsToExceptions' => true, 'crap4jThreshold' => 30, 'disallowTestOutput' => false, 'disallowTodoAnnotatedTests' => false, 'enforceTimeLimit' => false, 'excludeGroups' => array(), 'failOnRisky' => false, 'failOnWarning' => false, 'groups' => array(), 'processIsolation' => false, 'processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist' => false, 'registerMockObjectsFromTestArgumentsRecursively' => false, 'repeat' => false, 'reportHighLowerBound' => 90, 'reportLowUpperBound' => 50, 'reportUselessTests' => true, 'reverseList' => false, 'stopOnError' => false, 'stopOnFailure' => false, 'stopOnIncomplete' => false, 'stopOnRisky' => false, 'stopOnSkipped' => false, 'stopOnWarning' => false, 'strictCoverage' => false, 'timeoutForLargeTests' => 60, 'timeoutForMediumTests' => 10, 'timeoutForSmallTests' => 1, 'verbose' => false), true)
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\TextUI\Command.php:195)
  at PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(array('./bin/phpunit', '--colors=always'), true)
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\src\TextUI\Command.php:148)
  at PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
     (bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\phpunit:17)
  at include('C:\\cygwin64\\home\\www\\navitia-tools\\bin\\.phpunit\\phpunit-6.5\\phpunit')
     (vendor\symfony\phpunit-bridge\bin\simple-phpunit:261)
  at require('C:\\cygwin64\\home\\www\\navitia-tools\\vendor\\symfony\\phpunit-bridge\\bin\\simple-phpunit')
     (bin\phpunit:18)
```

My security setup if this can help :

```html
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        user:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            # pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: user
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                provider: user
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
```

Also for information (as the error is a PDO exception, I am using a pgsql database)

Your help would be very welcome,

Thanks for your support,

Comment: is this unit test or functional test?

Comment: Hi, this is a functional test :
class BackendControllerTest extends WebTestCase

Comment: And I am using a pgsql db

Comment: Try to pass `null` instead of `password$`. That's in the example in the official documentation.